# Angular http request with interface: statusText: "Unknown Error"

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http

I am trying to call an example API (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) in Angular via the use of an interface.

However I am getting the following error. **ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}**

My code for my TS file is below

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface Post {
  title: string;
  body: string;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.getData();

  }

  getData() {
    this.http.get<Post>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(res => {
      let postTitle = res.title;
      console.log(postTitle);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried your code and its working at my end. Only problem was that `res` returns array so it will be `res[0].title`.

Comment: thanks, though I need all the values of title so I guess a for loop is the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, your code has a few problems for one res is of Array type and if you want to access your objects property you'll have to loop through it (perhaps something like this:)

```
let postTitle = [];
this.http.get<Post>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(res => {
  res.forEach(element => {
  postTitle.push(element);
});
  console.log(postTitle);
});
```

and I strongly recommend to call an API via a service don't do it in a component.

Comment: thanks, yes i will do that. I just wanted to try an interface in a test call

Answer (score 1):

So I tried to replicate this with
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njzmwr

I found an issue that, your current api is returning data as an array so either selects the data by the filter from array or something else.
pls check the above-mentioned URL

Answer (score 0):

The API returns and `Array` of `Post`S. Try:

```
getData() {
  this.http.get<Post[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(res => {
    let postTitle = res[0].title;
    console.log(postTitle);
  });
}
```

HTH